# How to download a pdf in a html page in webview

Tags: android, html, webview

I have a forms.html file on the server. It shows links to pdfs to download. When I click the links on browser it downloads without problem. But when I try to download it in the app, nothing happens. How can I download the pdfs on the link in html pages on webview?

html code

```
   <a href="somepdfurl" class="external"><img src="formlar/'.$resim.'" alt="" title="" /></a>
```

Webview

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/web"

    ></WebView>
```

Comment: I see no pdf to begin with.

Comment: sorry, I am editing it. Its the "Link" in href

Comment: That is no url. You should be more exact.